# Spring MVC equivalent of nginx's try_files

Tags: spring-mvc, nginx

I have a Tomcat server that is serving a Spring MVC application.

I'd like to implement a static servlet for a certain path and I'd like it to behave in a manor equivalent to the nginx `try_files` directive:

```
...
root /my/path/to/app

location /app {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
...
```

For those unfamiliar with nginx:

I'd like the servlet to map the `/app` path directly to the `/webapp/app` directory.  If it finds the static file inside the directory that matches the request, great, return that content.  Otherwise return `/webapp/app/index.html` file.

For example, if my directory looks like this:

```
/webapp
    /app
        index.html
        existing-file.js
        /sub-dir
            file.js
```

then...

```
mydomain.com/app                     returns    /webapp/app/index.html
mydomain.com/app/index.html          returns    /webapp/app/index.html
mydomain.com/app/non-existant-file   returns    /webapp/app/index.html
mydomain.com/app/existing-file.js    returns    /webapp/app/existing-file.js
mydomain.com/app/sub-dir/file.html   returns    /webapp/sub-dir/file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem serving VueJS frontend from Spring app.
I use HTML5 history mode, so URI can contain some paths managed by frontend.
Spring app serves only `/api/**` endpoints.

AFAIK, there are no direct equivalent to try_files.

Basic idea is to create additional mapping which returns "index.html" on any request to "frontend" paths.
I don't know the way to create mapping for `/**` and give it lowest priority - this is the main difference from nginx, which chooses most specifically matching rule.

So I created a mapping which conforms to all paths except `/api/**`, `/js/**`, `/css/**`, `/fonts/**`, and index.html itself.
Most likely you'll need to adapt regex to your needs.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Controller
  static class Routes {
    @RequestMapping(
     value = "{_:^(?!index\\.html|api|css|js|fonts).*}/**",
     method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
      return "/index.html";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think is the closest to try_files is to let Spring boot try to serve the files, but if can't find then serve an error page instead, that can be redirected to something else, e.g.: index.html

```
/**
 * Redirects errors (including 404) to the index.html .
 */
@Controller
public class ErrorHandlerController implements ErrorController {

    /**
     * error handling.
     * 
     * @return home controller
     */
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String error() {
        return "paht/subpath/index.html";
    }

}
```